# Using Async/Await with array map to insert data into a postgres table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, async-await, promise

I am new to promises and unsure what I am missing from my code below as unfortunately my req.body jobGroups are not being inserted within my postgres table.

Within my index.js express code, I have the following. FYI, some sections of code have been left out.

The value of req.body is:

```
{
    "jobName": "ABC",
    "jobType": "1",
    "jobGroups": [
        {
            "jobGroupName": "A1",
        },
        {
            "jobGroupName": "B2",
        }       
    ]
}
```

When I call my route `/process-job` from my client, I see that the record is created within my `my_jobs` table but when it comes to processing the `my_job_groups` table, nothing is getting inserted.

I basically need to get both A1 and B2 created within the `my_job_groups` table using the job_id returned from the `my_jobs` insert.

Not sure if I am using my promises and async/await correctly?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");


app.post("/process-job", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { jobName, jobType } = req.body
    const jobDetails = req.body.jobGroups;

    const theJob = await pool.query(        
        "INSERT INTO my_jobs (job_name, job_type) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING job_id", 
            [ jobName, jobType ]
    );
    let jobId = theJob.rows[0];

    try {
      const promises = jobDetails.map(async jobDetail => {       
        let newJob = await pool.query(        
          "INSERT INTO my_job_groups (job_id, job_group_name) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING job_group_id", 
              [ jobId, jobDetails.jobGroupName ]
        );

        return {
          id: newJob.rows[0]
        }
      })

      const results = await Promise.all(promises)
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err.messasge);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err.messasge);
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks fine, are there any problems? The nested `try` blocks appear unnecessary, and you probably want to return an appropriate http response. Btw, you probably want to use a single pool client (per request) instead of one client per query (with `pool.query`).

Comment: @Bergi - could you please explain what you exactly mean wrt "you probably want to use a single pool client (per request) instead of one client per query (with pool.query)" ?

Comment: See https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling and https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions/.

Comment: @Bergi - since I will be performing multiple queries as above where I will need the `job_id` within my_jobs as part of my other insert query for `my_job_groups`, should I in actual fact be using `A pooled client with async/await` as per doco?

Comment: Yes. Unless for some reason you wouldn't want to use transactions?

Comment: @Bergi - my only issue is that I am getting an error when I place `const client = await pool.connect()` inside my `app.post("/process-job", async (req, res) => {` - I am getting the following error: `debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);                              TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined` I am new to this and unsure how to solve this issue?

Comment: That would be really weird, I see no reason why `req` would be `undefined`. Should not be related to the pool usage though.

Comment: @Bergi - unsure where to go from here or what to try as I really need to use transactions?

Comment: Maybe [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you post your code attempt to use transactions as a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi - posted. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732916/issue-when-trying-to-use-node-postgres-transactions-pooled-client-with-async-a

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all your code into one `try/catch` block is enough. When insert to `my_job_groups`, `job_group_name` should be `jobDetail.jobGroupName` instead of `jobDetails.jobGroupName`.

And, I think should be better if your API returns a response to the client.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");


app.post("/process-job", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { jobName, jobType, jobGroups: jobDetails } = req.body // destruct to get all properties

    const job = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO my_jobs (job_name, job_type) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING job_id",
      [jobName, jobType],
    );
    const jobId = job.rows[0];

    const promises = jobDetails.map(async jobDetail => {
      const newJob = await pool.query(
        "INSERT INTO my_job_groups (job_id, job_group_name) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING job_group_id",
        [jobId, jobDetail.jobGroupName] // jobDetail.jobGroupName instead of jobDetails.jobGroupName
      );

      return {
        id: newJob.rows[0],
      };
    });

    const result = await Promise.all(promises);

     res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err); // print out message object
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }); // response with status 500
  }
});
```