# Issue when trying to use node-postgres transactions - pooled client with async/await

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, async-await, node-postgres

I am attempting to use node-postgres transactions - see [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions)

I am specifically trying to use a pooled client with async/await, but am receiving an error in doing so.

My `db.js` file used below has the following contents:

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "mydb"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");


app.post("/process-job", async (req, res) => {

  const client = await pool.connect()
```

With placing the `const client = await pool.connect()` inside my `app.post("/process-job"` I am getting the following error:

```
debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
```

If I remove the `(req, res)`, it then works fine, i.e there are no errors.

Can anyone assist with what is the issue?

Comment: You need to show us in context where the line of code `debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);` is located and show us the surrounding code, blocks, etc...  Show us the entire request handler - all the code for it.  Right now you're asking about an error and NOT showing us where that error occurs in your code.  I would guess that somewhere in your code, you've declared `req` somewhere else that conflicts with the `req` in this code, but since you haven't disclosed that code, there's nothing we can do but guess.

Comment: @jfriend00 - fyi, I actually searched the whole contents of my js file and there is no reference to `debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);` and I have not declared `req` anywhere in my code. This is only being used as parameters.

Comment: We still need to see the code for your whole request handler that causes the error to occur.

Comment: And, it would probably help to see the whole stack trace from the error.

Comment: @ArthurJ If this `debug` call is not found in your code, it's probably in *express.js* - post the stack trace to confirm. And if it is, that means you're likely calling an express method somewhere in the wrong way - please show us the entire code, as a [mcve].

Comment: @Bergi - managed to track down the issue

Answer (score 0):

Found that the actual issue was that I need to also bring in `pg.Client` as part of my `db.js` file above, which now looks like this:

```
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "mydb"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

I was then able to use: `const client = await pool.connect()` with no errors.

Comment: Uh, no. Your code does not use `Client`, so you don't need to import it.